# Why is "action_mailer.perform_caching" included under the umbrella of request forgery protection in config/environments/test.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, actionmailer

Rails v5.1.6, Ruby 2.3.3

In my newly-generated Rails application, I see the following code in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
# Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

All the related sections of code in this file seem to be delimited by comments, including this section.  To me, that implies the two uncommented lines of code are related to each other, and are both meant to fall under the umbrella of request forgery protection (as stated in the comment).

I get why a line such as `action_controller.allow_forgery_protection` would fall under this category, but it isn't readily apparent to me why `action_mailer.perform_caching` would do so.  Most of the other lines of code are straightforward (especially with their respective comments), but nothing in this file makes this particular line of code any clearer, at least to me.

What is the connection between caching emails and request forgery?  Or am I interpreting the delimiting incorrectly, i.e. are emails in fact *not* related to request forgery?

**Update:** I suspect this 2nd scenario might be the case (i.e. the two concepts might be unrelated), since in `config/environments/production.rb`, this same line of code is found in found in a config section which is unrelated to request forgery:

```
# Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
# config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
# config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "wms_#{Rails.env}"
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

However, a 2nd opinion wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: I believe they are not related to each other and perhaps they are wrongly grouped or it is missing a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're unrelated. You can see in [the current (future 6.0) template source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f5ac08180fbe3f4d9378f34e173f4ce1f8fc1a78/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/test.rb.tt#L29-L38) they're intended to be much more clearly separated, with blank lines and now even another also-unrelated setting in between.

The missing blank line seems to be a formatting error [introduced during Rails 5.0 development](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3d7b0d480467b17715941503b1fe598e57c13ac1), where `perform_caching` was added, and (because the template format makes it less clear) a preceding blank was not.

[Comparing the generated `config/environments/test.rb` between 5.1.6 and 5.2.1](http://railsdiff.org/5.1.6/5.2.1) confirms it looks better in the newer version (though that line does stand out as being one of the only settings in that file without a matching comment).